# 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'action.handler')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, poltergeist

I'm using ember with rails and poltergeist for testing!

It works just fine in development after i upgraded to ember-pre2 
but it throws the following error when closing an ember view in one test!

```
Failure/Error: click_on "X"
     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page:

       TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'action.handler')
```

that's the line https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-pre.2/lib/ember.js#L12330 in ember.js, and i have no glue why this happens..
when clicking on "X" there is only a simple transitionTo!